# Default cube not displayed

Tags: 3d-view

When I start Blender, the default cube is not displayed. Instead, only the center point of it is shown. When I add other meshes, I also see only the center point. How do I exit this strange mode?

[image]
[image]

EDIT:
I just found out, my other models now look crazy:
[image]

This one has a problem in user perspective:
[image]

Comment: Please add a screenshot to illustrate the problem.

Comment: @RayMairlot ok, done :)

Comment: weird, that seems when you remove all geometry to an object, or you scale it down to zero. Which Blender version? Do you see the vertices count?

Comment: about your update: other models in the same file? did you try a fresh .zip of blender?

Comment: @m.ardito I think I have much worse problem, all my old blends now look somewhat like huge intersecting polygons. These are from different file. I use the same Blender 2.77a from the official website, as I was using before.

Comment: can u attach a normal cube added file

Comment: @atek I attached the file! But I'm rather sure it will be fine.

Comment: Your file opens fine here and nothing looks out of the ordinary...

Comment: Yes, apparently something happened on my side, because all my old files now look crazy. Can it be a hardware problem or some openGL problem?

Comment: Yes your file open file with the normal cube . u can restart ur pc or laptop or uninstall and install a new fresh version 2.78a

Comment: @atek, restart didn't help, new version has exactly the same problem. Old blender 2.6 works.

Comment: I added more pictures. A few of the models seem ok. But whichever standard mesh I add, I see the central point only,  and most old meshes have these intersecting planes.

Comment: Crazy geometry problems are most likely pointing to hardware- or driver-related problems. Please edit your question and add more information about your operating system, your GPU and its driver version. I had once similar problems with another software because my GPU got a little too hot due to dust in the heatsink

Comment: @metaphor_set It is Nvidia GeForce GTX 560 Ti, driver 304.132, Ubuntu system, temperature is by 44.

Comment: Did you change something lately, before the problem appeared? Updated something? The Drivers are fairly old, according to NVIDIA's homepage...

Comment: @metaphor_set Not really, but Ubuntu has regular updates. I also got a problem with a splash screen of one program, it can be related. I'll see if new drivers work.

Comment: @metaphor_set installed a new driver and everything works fine now.

Comment: Yay, success! Sometimes Linux can be a little nasty with 3D acceleration and updates.

Answer (score -3):

[image] may be u have done this way so the cube is invisible and only the pivot point visible

Comment: No, there's the cube (?) there, look at the pivot. And, if @Noidea adds new objects, the same happens...

Comment: This didn't help. When I add other meshes, they all are displayed as central point. Even worse,  my  old slends went crazy! I'll add a picture.

Comment: @ noidea i mean attach a blend file with a cube save in that and not a image

Comment: @atek, I was talking about the picture of my old blends.

Comment: look the image i have attached