# Startup cube not display as other objects

Tags: transparency, .fbx, startup-file

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
I started to learn blender on Dell Latitude E7450 with Intel Corei7 in order to participate a contest but after the laptop crashed I switched to Hp Protect Smart with AMD A10-5750M APU with Radeon HD Graphic 2.50 Ghz. I first encountered this problem when running a blender on HP.(If I clicked on cube then it shows the edges).When I switched to the HP I first encountered this problem.Startup cube not show in object mode but if highlight all its vertices then it is displayed in semi-transparent view.After this manipulation, the object is displayed in a translucent manner.It is not over.New objects that i created was same as it except the circle.I don't know how to explain it but I'll show you.What it is?[image][image]I also became aware of this problem when importing a fbx character model[image: ![enter image description here]][8](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tf2Yv.png)Shall you help me please?Here are some similar questions that can help you:
[Default cube not displayed](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/67023/default-cube-not-displayed)
https://blenderartists.org/t/solved-solid-view-not-showing-the-default-cube/549643/9

Comment: Hello :). Since the A10-5750M APU is from *March 2013*, there might be some issues with compatibility. Perhaps [older Blender versions](https://download.blender.org/release/) will work better.

Comment: Thank you very much for that.It works